# How to find and measure arc length within an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Need some help.   I need to get length of the arc from Point A to Point B in centimeters as marked in image.  Also, we need to extract on the only leg nothing else that might be there in the image or might not be.  This is using Python and OpenCV.  I have been able to get only 2 largest contours from many of them but struggling to keep only to the largest one.  Below given is the current code.

```
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2

image_dir = "/home/rahul/Desktop/img-708/"

img = cv2.imread(image_dir+'side_left.jpg')

lower = np.array([0, 48, 80], dtype = "uint8")
upper = np.array([20, 255, 255], dtype = "uint8")

# keep looping over the frames in the video


# resize the frame, convert it to the HSV color space,
# and determine the HSV pixel intensities that fall into
# the speicifed upper and lower boundaries
frame = imutils.resize(img, width = 400)
converted = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
skinMask = cv2.inRange(converted, lower, upper)

# apply a series of erosions and dilations to the mask
# using an elliptical kernel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
skinMask = cv2.erode(skinMask, kernel, iterations = 2)
skinMask = cv2.dilate(skinMask, kernel, iterations = 2)

# blur the mask to help remove noise, then apply the
# mask to the frame
skinMask = cv2.GaussianBlur(skinMask, (3, 3), 0)
skin = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = skinMask)

# show the skin in the image along with the mask
cv2.imwrite(image_dir+'output.jpg', np.hstack([skin]))

#image = cv2.imshow(np.hstack([skin])
image_dir = "/home/rahul/Desktop/img-708/"

image = cv2.imread(image_dir+'output.jpg')
#image = cv2.imread(pass)
shifted = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image, 21, 51)
cv2.imshow("Input", image)

# convert the mean shift image to grayscale, then apply
# Otsu's thresholding
gray = cv2.cvtColor(shifted, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)

# find contours in the thresholded image
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
print("[INFO] {} unique contours found".format(len(cnts)))

# loop over the contours
for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
    # draw the contour
    ((x, y), _) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.putText(image, "#{}".format(i), (int(x) - 10, int(y)),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Original Image

[image]

Output image of my code:

[image]

Comment: Please provide more informatin on the images and formulate a problem. Are points A and B always the lowest points in the foot object or will foot orientation differ? You only find objects but I don't see that you even tried to separate the foot. Show some effort.

Comment: @Piglet:  Apologies as it was not added...you can view the original image which is the input and after running my code "output image of my code".

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that the foot will always be in this orientation (no rotation, no upside-down).

To keep the biggest contour, you can:

- iterate over the contours and calculate the contour area with: `cv2.contourArea`
- itearte over the contours and get the bounding rect with: `cv2.boundingRect` in order to keep the contour with the biggest bounding box area

With `cv2.boundingRect` you can get in the same time the width of the bounding rectangle and so the "global" length of the foot.

If you want the arc length, one possible (and more tricky) solution would be to find the bottom extrema points and then iterate over the contour points and store only contour points between these extrema points.

The arc length can be calculated with `cv2.arcLength`.

Image result with bounding rectangle and extrema points:

[image]

Image result with bottom contour points:

[image]

I got:

```
bounding rectangle width: 208 px
approximate arc length: 237.811 px
```

But you have to keep in mind that without a calibration object in the image and with a single camera, you will not be able to retrieve the measure in cm, only in pixel unit.

Edit: as requested the source code in C++ as I don't have Python, should be easily translated to Python.

Warning: specific and trivial code that may not work with more generic or other data.

The trivial code to get the index of the biggest contour:

```
size_t id_max_area = 0;
double max_area = 0.0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
    if(max_area < area) {
        max_area = area;
        id_max_area = i;
    }
}
```

The (tricky) code to get the extrema points:

```
cv::Point bottom_left(img.cols, 0), bottom_right(0, 0);
for(size_t i = 0; i < contours[id_max_area].size(); i++) {
    cv::Point contour_pt = contours[id_max_area][i];
    if(bottom_left.x > contour_pt.x)
        bottom_left.x = contour_pt.x;

    if(bottom_left.y < contour_pt.y)
        bottom_left.y = contour_pt.y;

    if(bottom_right.x < contour_pt.x)
        bottom_right.x = contour_pt.x;

    if(bottom_right.y < contour_pt.y)
        bottom_right.y = contour_pt.y;
}
```

The (also tricky) code to keep the bottom contour points:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> bottom_contour;
for(size_t i = 0; i < contours[id_max_area].size(); i++) {
    cv::Point contour_pt = contours[id_max_area][i];
    if(contour_pt.x >= bottom_left.x && contour_pt.x <= bottom_right.x
        && contour_pt.y > bottom_left.y - 15) {
        bottom_contour.push_back(contour_pt);
    }
}
double length = cv::arcLength(bottom_contour, false);
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code, as my job is on stake...I have just started up learning the computer vision and image processing techniques.....it would be an favour on me...pls

Comment: one more thing...i would also need the X and Y cordinates of the arc

Comment: Keep in mind that the code is very specific and will certainly not work with other input data.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  However, i a very much new and only know python to great deal.  If you can share the complete code then i would decode it to Python after understanding the complete code as to how you are reading the images.